# Running different Powershell startup Scripts on Different Users

Tags: powershell

Recently I decided to split My Pc into two Users one for gaming and one for work to increase my work productivity. Now I am wondering is there a way to:

1. run a PowerShell script on UserLogin Opening Certain Apps/Programs and maybe even putting in custom input like login info for immediate login.
2. run different scripts depending on the logged-in User.

Comment: You can use group policy or Task Scheduler to run PS on login for specific users.

Comment: Blocking "Solitaire" could be done by removing NTFS permissions to the exe for your work user, JK. I agree with @Scepticalist, your best option is the Task Scheduler or even the old "Startup" folder might be bit easier to manage if the Task Scheduler is new to you.